# OR behaviour in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following situation a map with a `false` boolean property. When I tried to assign the value with a `or` condition to another map, I received a `nil` and not `false` how I expected.

```
iex(1)> my_map = %{"email_sended" => false}                          
%{"a" => false}

iex(2)> other_map = %{ email_sended: my_map["email_sended"] || my_map[:email_sended] }
%{email_sended: nil}

iex(3)> other_map[:email_sended]
nil
```

My question is, there is a concise way to do that without having to make an `if` conditional like this?

```
iex(4)> if Map.has_key?(my_map, "email_sended"), do: my_map["email_sended"], else: my_map[:email_sended]
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for a short inline solution, just ORing it with false will handle the nil case:

```rb
iex> my_map = %{"email_sended" => false}
%{"email_sended" => false}
iex> my_map["email_sended"] || my_map[:email_sended] || false
false
```

If you're looking for more robust solutions, `case` and `with` are good options:

```rb
iex> case my_map do
...>   %{"email_sended" => sent} -> sent
...>   %{email_sended: sent} -> sent
...>   %{} -> false
...> end
false
```

```rb
iex> with :error <- Map.fetch(my_map, "email_sended"),
...>      :error <- Map.fetch(my_map, :email_sended) do
...>   false
...> else
...>   {:ok, sent} ->
...>     sent
...> end
false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `||, && and !` operators documentation, you can find:

> all values except false and nil will evaluate to true:

```
iex> false || 11
11
```

This means that `||` operator cannot be used reliably for such things.

In general your approach is wrong, you should know with what types of keys you are working, since there are advantages/disadvantages to using atoms/strings keys.

If you still want to make this work, the best approach would be to make a helper function:

```
def get_key(map, key) when is_map(map) and is_binary(key) do
  case map[key] do
    nil -> map[String.to_atom(key)]
    value -> value
  end
end
```

However this is still not perfect since the atom key can also be absent and you will get nil.

Answer (score 1):

A (sometimes considered dirty) trick to convert about any value to a boolean is the *double not*:

```
iex> !!(nil || true)
true

iex> !!(nil || false)
false
```

But be aware that any value other than `nil` or `false` is considered true, so don't fall into this trap:

```
iex> !!(true || "on") # seems to work
true

iex> !!(false || "off") # oops
true
```

But before you start using this, it might be a good idea to remove the inconsistency in your application regarding the use of both string and atom keys for the same piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, the most robust way would be to use [`Map.get/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Map.html?#get/3) that explicitly checks for the existence of the key.

```rb
other_map = %{email_sended:
  Map.get(my_map, "email_sended", my_map[:email_sended]) 
}
#⇒ %{email_sended: false}
```

It might be even done twice.

```rb
value = 
  Map.get(my_map, "email_sended",
    Map.get(my_map, :email_sended, {:error, :not_found}))
other_map = %{email_sended: value}
#⇒ %{email_sended: false}
```